# The distribution of prime and semi-prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\alpha$ be an integer and $\rho_1,\rho_2$ some prime such that $\alpha=\rho_1\cdot\rho_2+1$, and $\beta$ the number of all semi-prime less than or equal to $\alpha$. Prove that:$\pi(\alpha)=\beta\pm1$, where $\pi(\alpha)$ is the prime-counting function.

Comment: For $\alpha = 2\cdot 3 + 1$, we have $\pi(\alpha) = 4$, but there are only two semiprimes not exceeding $7$, namely $4$ and $6$.

Comment: *less than or equal to $\alpha$*, so in your case/example the number of prime and semi-prime less than $7$ are $2,3,5$ and $4,6$ respectively, which is in my view doesn't contradict with the statement. @DanielFischer

Comment: $\pi(\alpha)$ is the number of primes less than _or equal to_ $\alpha$, in my example we have $\alpha = 7$ and $\pi(\alpha) = 4$. If you meant primes strictly less than $\alpha$, you should write $\pi(\alpha - 1)$ or $\pi(\alpha-1/2)$.

Comment: I didn't mean that the number of primes would be _strictly_ less than or equal to $\alpha$. What I mean that it could be **either** _less than_ $\alpha$ **or** _equal to_ $\alpha$. For example, $\alpha=2\cdot 5+1=11,$ then $\pi(\alpha)=\beta\pm1=\pi(11)=4+1$ that is, $2,3,5,7,11$. Again by $\pm$ I mean either $"+"$ or $"-"$, hope it helps. @DanielFischer

Comment: But then we have the immediate counterexamples $\alpha = 5 = 2\cdot 2 + 1$ with $\pi(\alpha) = 3$ and $\beta = 1$, and $\alpha = 7 = 2\cdot 3 + 1$ with $\pi(\alpha) = 4$ and $\beta = 2$. If you took $\pi(\alpha-1)$, one would need to go a little higher for counterexamples, $\alpha = 2\cdot 5 + 1 = 11$ would do if the assertion means $\lvert \pi(\alpha-1) - \beta\rvert = 1$, since we have four primes and four semiprimes strictly less than $11$, and regardless of the details of interpretation, for $\alpha = 40 = 3\cdot 13+1$ we have $\pi(\alpha) = 12$, and $\beta = 15$.

Comment: I got it, thanks for your response @DanielFischer